# Decode this Example of Dynamically Increasing Input Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been doing a huge amount of reading here and on other websites about how to dynamically increase an input field's width based on its content. All the solutions so far have only worked in part, but I have found a website where it works perfectly:

https://paper.fiftythree.com/search

They've even given some vague instruction as to how they did it:

http://making.fiftythree.com/fluid-text-inputs/

But I can't for the life of me work out how to implement this on my own website.

This is my form structure at the moment:

```
<form action="/" class="search-form">
  <input type="text" name="s" class="_input" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
  <button type="submit" class="_button">Search</button>
</form>
```

My reason for trying to do this is that the form as a whole has a border underneath it. I would then like text that is typed in to have its own border-bottom 'grow' with the text in a different colour. The input field being a smaller width with its own border works, but I am stuck on a smooth dynamic experience for its width.

Could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this example we can do this:

- Input positioned absolute with fixed `width` this never changes, and will get the data
- An element that will change the `width` based on the value from the input and the text transparent so that way we only see the input text.
- Centered elements creating the ilusion of increase of the width

```js
$('input').on('keypress', function() {
  $('span').text($(this).val())
})
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size:25px;
}
.container img, .container span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-right: -4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.container span {
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 250px;
}
.container input {
  width: 250px;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:inherit;
  padding: 0 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  background: transparent;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/50" alt="">
  <span>Type here</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type here">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/50" alt="">
</div>
```

---

<sub>Note: Still have some issues when deleting text, but you get the idea</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Will this work when the form field is submitted, since it's now a span element as far as I can tell rather than <input>?

Comment: @WillNicholls it's still the input that gets the value ... the span isn't visible it's just to create the illusion of growing

Comment: I see - thanks. This is probably really obvious, but where is this placed in relation to my <form> code then?

Comment: Well mate I'm sorry but i'm not going to write all the code for you @WillNicholls

Comment: Sorry it's just beyond my expertise which are very minimal.